# from objective-c iOS, AES128 encrypt - base64 encode - post to PHP - decode in PHP fails SOMETIMES

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

Here is what I am trying to do:

1) get plain NSString from the user

2) encrypt with AES128 with 16-bytes-long key(ex: 0123456789abcdef)

3) send it to PHP server

4) decrypt it into plain text

But if the input plain text is either too long or too short, decryption fails.

**Here is what I have done:**

The link https://tharindufit.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/aes128-encryption-in-ios-and-decryption-in-php/
provides

NSData+AEScrypt.h

NSData+AEScrypt.m

NSString+AEScrypt.h

NSString+AEScrypt.m

**inside ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NSString+AESCrypt.h"

...

-(void) sendPost {
//1. prepare 16-bytes long key
NSString *theKey = @"0123456789abcdef";

//2. prepare any plain NSString
NSString *plainString = @"abcdef";

//3. turn NSString into UTF-8 NSData
NSData *plainStringData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//4. turn UTF-8 NSData into AES128 Encrypted NSData with key
NSData *aesData = [plainStringData AES128EncryptWithKey: theKey];

//5. encode AES data into Base64-encoded NSString
NSString *base64String = [aesData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

//check what the client is sending to the server
NSLog("Client plain text:%@ encrypted text:%@", plainString, base64String);
//Logs:
//Client plain text: abcdef encrypted text: iD+22cYZOlopuScGn42rAg==


/** do normal POST request to server ************/
//6. send 'base64String' to server
//set up parameter
NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@", base64String];
NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//set up URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com/myserver.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPBody:parameterData];

//set up as POST method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

**inside myserver.php**

```
<?php
//1. receive data from client
$data = $_POST['data'];

//2. check what the server received
echo "Before decrypt:".$data
//this echoes:
//Before decrypt:iD 22cYZOlopuScGn42rAg== 

//3. set up the same key as client's key
$key = "0123456789abcdef";

//4. decrypt AES
$decoded_data = decrypt_password($data, "0123456789abcdef");

//5. see the result
echo "After decrypt:".$decoded_data;
//this echoes:
//After decrypt: abcdef




function decrypt_password($pass,$key)
{
$base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;

$res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

$decrypted = $res_non;
$dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

$padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);

return  $decrypted;
}

?>
```

if everything goes correct, I should get in NSLog as:

```
Client plain text: abcdef encrypted text: iD+22cYZOlopuScGn42rAg==
```

and from PHP as:

```
Before decrypt:iD 22cYZOlopuScGn42rAg==
After decrypt:abcdef
```

But if the NSString *plainString is either too long or too short,
I get from PHP:

```
Before decrypt:pQGKv22BszWe5WN b9oOtQ==
After decrypt:
```

Meaning, PHP can't decrypt it. 
Also, I realized that '+' signs are gone in "Before decrypt:" echo. but this doesn't seem to be the problem because sometimes the decryption works.

**My question is
Why does decryption fail for plain NSString that is either too long or too short??
How can i fix this?? I can't seem to find any solution for this. Please help..**

Comment: It's just a possibility but PHP and Objective C may apply the padding in a different way. Good luck

Comment: Can you hint me with a solution as well?

Comment: As your PHP code seems good to me, all I can give you as advice is: Go test the cases which are not working, find out the difference between the working and not working cases, the reason why this difference causes an error and then do prefix/postfix treatment to correct this difference while not corrupting the encrypted chain. Good luck

Comment: mcrypt uses non-standard null padding and even states that the padding will fail if the data has a last byte on 0x00. Common Crypto and the non-bozo world uses PKCS#7 padding. PKCS#7 padding is a superset of PKCS#5.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

When encrypted string contains '+' signs, PHP turns it into blank space because '+' sign is reserved.

So, use urlencode() and urldecode() for it like this:

```
<?php
$key = 'secretkey';
$string = $_GET['data'];

$string = urlencode($string);
$string = str_replace("+", "%2B",$string);
$string = urldecode($string);
$output = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

?>
```

Comment: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES and does not specify a 256 bit key. It specifies a 256 bit block size which is not supported by AES.